# Re-sizing SharePoint 2013 Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-calendar

The calendar app cannot change the size of the month view cells.The Height and Width in Appearance,when the input is small, it brings scrollbars and we don't want that. How can I make it small in size, if possible without editing the source code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way i did it was to edit the page with the calendar and insert > web part > media and Content > script Editor. Then edit the Webpart so the "edit snippet" will appear and insert the code from this link: [here](http://erikswenson.blogspot.de/2013/04/small-calendar-for-sharepoint-2010-2013.html)

This is the code I used:

```
<style> 
/**** Small Calendar ***/ 
.ms-acal-item{height: 10px !important;} 
.ms-acal-sdiv, 
.ms-acal-mdiv, 
.ms-acal-ctrlitem, 
.ms-acal-month-weeksel, 
.ms-acal-title, 
.ms-acal-vlink a{display:none;}
.ms-acal-month-top span{display: none;} 
.ms-acal-summary-itemrow TD DIV{height: 15px !important;} 
</style>
```

This line here:

```
.ms-acal-vlink a{display:none;}
```

was added to get rid of the add link semiappearing in the small cells of the calendar.

Hope it helps, will take less than a minute to implement.

Comment: Thanks @ConAchilleos , but why do we get scrollbars at the bottom? Also the link you have given me, doesn't exist.

Comment: sorry fixed the link! where do you get scrollbars? I'm using the same code and I don't get any

Comment: Now that is how it looks after putting in the script

Comment: 404 - file not found... could you upload again?

Comment: Click here: http://goo.gl/w8pKAU

Comment: So what do you propose?

Comment: I see that you inserted the calendar in a layout - which is a box fitting exaclty the calendar? Can you try making that box a bit bigger? Normaly it should fit but there is a scaling thing with SP that determines when to use scrollbars and prob thinks the web-part does not fit

Comment: Now the question comes, how do we edit the size of the box?

Comment: I put my calendar in a normal team-site, which offers a text-layout Option giving different number of box numbers and sizes. But from the your screen-shot I cannot really tell what kind of site template you are using. Shall I assume you are using a blog template?

Comment: Yes. Because that is what I think. How would I be able to detect the site template?

Comment: Actually you can first try to Change the number of px on the first and last line to make the calendar a bit smaller and see if it'll get rid of the bars. (e.g. 5px) If it gets rid of the bars, a bit of trial and error (increasing the px number bit by bit) until you figure out the Maximum numbers without the bars :)

Comment: The moment I change the length of the height and width, the scrollbar appears even if its 1px.

Comment: well... unfortunately resizing the box (app part) falls a bit outside my knowledge. I just did a small "resize sharepoint blog app part" Google search and there are solutions but a bit hard to post them in a comment. May I suggest to post another question here on the site to do that - so someone more qualified can see - or maybe dig around on the web to see if there is an easy solution. Sorry I couldn't help with the slidebar problem :/

ps. nice blog btw :)

Answer (score 1):

We also used such CSS-tricks to change the default behavior of the standard SharePoint caledar, but were not satisfied with the result (for example, if we had a lot of events with long titles, they pushed the borders of the cells).

At the end, we decided to use [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/), a free JavaScript based solution with a lot of references, samples in SharePoint (like [this](http://www.shillier.com/archive/2013/04/10/using-the-fullcalendar-plugin-in-sharepoint-2013-apps.aspx), [this](https://www.pena.id/2014/06/sharepoint-aggregated-calendar-view-using-content-search-web-part-jquery-fullcalendar/), [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/786787/Sharepoint-FullCalendar-jquery-View), [this](http://joshmccarty.com/2011/11/sharepoint-jquery-and-fullcalendar%E2%80%94now-with-spservices/) or [this](http://joshmccarty.com/2011/06/display-events-from-a-sharepoint-calendar-using-jquery-and-fullcalendar/)), and a great amount of flexibility and customizations. Now we have nearly full control on the rendering.

Comment: it doesn't show how to reduce the size but how to make the events visible.